# Is there a way to perform "SELECT JSON ..." with the QueryBuilder in the CQL drivers?

Tags: json, cassandra, cql, cql3, datastax-java-driver

I dug through datastax's QueryBuilder source code and I can't find a way to a query like:

```
select JSON * from myTable;
```

Also, it would be fairly easy to make a subclass to do this, but that is thwarted by the package protection of the constructors in `com.datastax.driver.core.querybuilder.Select`.

Is there any way to do this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now it's not possible but you will be able to use a new `select().raw()` method to inject arbitrary string like "JSON *".

See the resolution of this JIRA: https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-1086

---

Added new syntax:

```
select()
    .cast(fcall("writetime", column("country")), DataType.text())
    .from("artists").limit(2);
```

I also exposed the raw method in the top-level API, so this will serve as a workaround for this kind of issue in the future:

```
select = select().raw("CAST(writetime(country) AS text)").from("artists").limit(2);
```

---